# Index Multiple Entities using Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, indexing, hibernate-search

Is it possible to Index multiple entities within same index using Hibernate Search ? I have 3 entities User, Category and Campaign. These entities are not related to each other.

I need to provide a functionality where user can search across these entities.  Similar to facebook search or Quora search.

Eg: https://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=Stackoverflow will show all the groups, pages etc with the given query string.

Answer (score 5):

I do realize that this is a rather old question, but I'll still post an answer to this question as it might some day still help someone.

Yes, it is possible. How you can do that is described here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-sharing-indexes

Comment: Still, for me this is erasing other entities and reindexing only the current entity I ask to reindex. The command `ftem.createIndexer().startAndWait();` is triggering a PurgeAllLuceneWork and then a stream work of reinserting the current entities.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible (AFAIK) to index multiple entities within the same index, though you can query multiple indexes at the same time using the `FullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(Query, Class<?> ...)` method.  In your case, the usage would be `fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, User.class, Category.class, Campaign.class);`.